# Glass/Transmissive Principled BSDF doesn't refract images in planes in eevee

Tags: materials, light, eevee-render-engine, glass

I was thinking about adding a CG crystal object to a video, and thought about putting the image behind so it would have the correct distortions and stuff, but it only refracts the image behind if I use cycles. I've tried enabling refraction in the Screen Space Reflections tab and Screen Space Refraction in the material tab but it still doesn't work, but it does with actual mesh like cubes and so on.
Is there a way to fix this using eevee? It honestly would be understandable if it wasn't

[image: Preview in Eevee][image: Preview in Cycles]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Added material setup, it doesn't get simpler than that folks

Comment: Could you please add an image of the glass shader setup you are using?